# Overriding onTouchEvent with Flixel (Android port)

Tags: android, touchscreen, touch-event, flixel

So I followed [Mathew Casperson's *Making Games on Android* Tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2010/01/04/making-games-on-android.aspx) and got a small game running a few days ago, now I am trying to switch the controls to touchscreen instead of the D-pad.

I am running into some problems and was wondering if anyone here could help me.  Flixel doesn't have any built in touchscreen functions so I am overriding `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in my Activity (`FlixelDemo.java` in the tutorial) and hopefully getting the coordinates of the touch.

I then have a function in my `Player.java` that given the touch coordinates could tell me whether my player has been touched.

The problem I am having is trying to figure out how to get to/call that function (`isCollision`) from in the activity.

It seems that I can only override the onTouchEvent in `FlixelDemo.java` and that I can only use the `isCollision` function in `GameState.java` where I add the player.

How do I get the info from the overridden touch event to any of my other classes? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or help me figure out a different way of implementing touch events?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, `FlixelDemo` is really just a container for `org.flixel.FlxGameView` (via the `res/layout/main.xml` file).

The `onTouchEvent` method can be applied to any `View`, so you can apply it to just the flixel viewport.

And in fact, that's probably what you want to do here: Add your handler directly to `FlxGameView.java`, and then let it call a method on the internal `GameThread` class.

It's already handling the other events this way. See `FlxGameView.onKeyDown` (and the associated `FlxGameView.GameThread.doKeyDown`) for a good example.